# Can I reset my followers' skills?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is it possible to reset and re-select the skills that I want my followers to have?

I want my Templar to be able to heal more, so I would like to change the skills that I originally selected for him.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Yes.

There used to be an option to reset the chosen skills, but it was removed in 2.0 (or shortly before that) to be replaced by a simpler system:

#### Just re-select them.

I.e. click on the other (greyed out) skill to assign that skill.

---

Siderant: It took me some time to find out as well. Simpler does not mean more intuitive. I mean, who sees a greyed out button (w/o mouseover animation) and clicks it? IMO Blizzard should probably switch to highlighting the selected skill instead of greying out the other one.

Maybe someone should point Blizzard to [UX SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: Oh, didn't expect it to be as simple as that. I thought it was more like a one time choice. Thanks, I will try it when I'm at home.

Comment: Yeah, I spent some time looking for the missing retrain button...

Comment: As a newcomer I figured this out immediately and had no trouble with the interface at all.